# How to deal with different file.separator on Windows and UNIX in java

Tags: java, file

I'm reviewing my code

My Java application runs on Windows and Unix using Java 6 and manipulates files. I know I can use the file.separator to get the file separator in a filesystem independent way but if I ever use specify windows file separator char directly because is the '\' which is also the Java escape character I can't do manipulation of the file path.  So in my code I've always stored the filepath in unix notation by replacing \' with '/' ,and these paths are stored in a database so I thought there was an escaping problem there as well. So I was under the illusion that trying to use file.separator would also fail because it would return '\' rather than '\' but now realise only need \ if I actually explicity specify it myself in quotes.

Now I'm thinking this is all unnecessary and as long as I always use file.separator I don't need to do this conversion, am I right ?

EDIT:
Found a case where it seems to be a problem

```
"C:\Fred\test1.txt".split("\\\\");
"C:\Fred\test1.txt".split(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
```

if I want to split the string by \ I have double it up because \ has special meaning in a regular expression, so the line using file.separator fails with

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1466)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
```

but on unix no such requirement the corresponding '/'  should not be escaped

EDIT 2:
This question has been asked before [Splitting filenames using system file separator symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336293/splitting-filenames-using-system-file-separator-symbol) the solution boils down to using Pattern.quote() around the input or trying to use file methods rather regular expressions. Both a little uneccessary I would prefer it if files could be viewed ins a system independent way, I not that Path in Java 7 has the same problem.

EDIT 3:
Also seeing a problem with reading/writing from db, created a separate question on that [Storing Windows Path in Database and retrieving with Hibernate using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242543/storing-windows-path-in-database-and-retrieving-with-hibernate-using-java)

Comment: For EDIT 2: `Pattern.quote(File.Seperator)` does work in both cases right? In windows it will be returned with 4 quotes and in Unix with 2 - which is what you need?

Comment: Yes, Pattern.quote() does work, that's what I've done but its a shame that I have to take some special steps because of Windows  pathnames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are right - if you use File.Seperator you dont need any additional escaping because in Windows it is already escaped for you. From the java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar).

```
separatorChar

public static final char separatorChar

The system-dependent default name-separator character. 
This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. 
On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/';
on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\\'.
```

Comment: Added problem when using regular expressions