# Split string by \\

Tags: java, string

my String is `name="D:\\Tool\\BondTable\\New_Table.csv";`
I want to split it by `"\\"`.

my code is

```
String [] output = name.replaceAll("\\",",").split(",");
```

I am getting below error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
```

Comment: You need to split the string by "\\\\" because if you use "\\" the compiler will assume you trying to cater for one escape character "\". Two escape characters represent one escape character and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use four backslashes in your regex to match a single backslash and you don't need to have an intermediate `replaceAll` function.

```
String name="D:\\Tool\\BondTable\\New_Table.csv";
String parts[] = name.split("\\\\");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[D:, Tool, BondTable, New_Table.csv]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use use [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name="D:\\Tool\\BondTable\\New_Table.csv";
        String pattern = Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
        String[] splittedFileName = name.split(pattern);

        for (String string : splittedFileName) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }
```

And the output is;

```
D:
Tool
BondTable
New_Table.csv
```

For more information, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336293/splitting-filenames-using-system-file-separator-symbol).

Answer (score 2):

`String [] output = name.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"),",").split(",");`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a *similar* result with Java 7's `java.nio` classes, without regular expressions:

```
Path p = Paths.get("D:\\Tool\\BondTable\\New_Table.csv");
System.out.println(p.getRoot());
for (Path sub: p) {
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

**Output**

```
D:\
Tool
BondTable
New_Table.csv
```

**Comment**

As you can see, the root itself is printed with a trailing separator for some reason.

Other than that, it's pretty much your desired result.

Comment: This is a better solution because it doesn't rely on the system dependent path separator (File.separator). This is \ on Windows and / on Unix. This might even work on Zip file entries, which can be either (even both on different files in the same zip file).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String [] output = name.split("\\\\");
```